# What are the most famous qualitative methods to study and analyse a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I need to study the Duffing-van der Pol equation
$$ \ddot x - x + x^3 = \varepsilon (p_1 + p_2 x - x^2) \dot x $$
using a few qualitative methods but the problem is that I don't know any, so can you recommend some or help by pointing me to the place in which I should look? thank you in advance!

Comment: The book I used in John Guckenheimer's introductory-level course is [this one](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493963874) by Schaeffer and Cain. It's almost entirely focused on qualitative study of nonlinear ODEs, so you should be able to find what you want at the level of a student first learning about dynamics.